# ionic keyboard events not firing on android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

After adding crosswalk to my ionic app  I faced many issues with keyboard  and overlapping content
the only solution was adding adjust nothing then get the keyboard height
as mentioned in ionic keyboard plugin

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow',function(e){
$(".msg_footer").css("bottom", e.keyboardHeight + "px");
 alert('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);    
 });
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide',function(e){
   $(".msg_footer").css("bottom","0px");
alert('Keyboard height is: ' + e.keyboardHeight);    
});
```

with adjustResize events are fired and I got the alert message

but with adjustNothing ,alerts are not fired any more

here is my app run function I set ionic full scree to true

```
 myapp.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
  }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
 ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;
 });
```

});

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where I saw some flickering on Android 5 and I had to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to get rid of that. I also get the keyboard events fired.

Try with adjustPan to see if it works for you.

Comment: but with adjust pan the keyboard will overlap the footer input field

Comment: In my tests, the adjustPan scrolls and pans the input whenever it receives focus. I placed an input at the bottom of the view inside the ion-content and it seems to work just fine. Tested on Android Lollipop w/Crosswalk.

Comment: my input is outside ionic content and inside ionic footer bar

Comment: This solution worked for me :) My manifest file had `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` initially. Setting it to **adjustPan** only works.

And also setting `ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;` is important as well.

Comment: should i create a new activity or edit the existing activity?